# Execution order of filters implementing IAuthorizationFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject.web.mvc

I created a filter named PrincipalFilter implementing IAuthorizationFilter interface, to set a custom IPrincipal and IIdentity. This i a global filter.
I use dependency injection via Ninject (3.0) so I register my filter as this in a NinjectModule :

```
this.BindFilter<PrincipalFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
```

This works fine. At least that's what I thought.

There is a case that is the problem. The important fact is that the property IsAuthenticated of my custom IIdentity does not always return true when the user name is known (the user can be recognized but not authenticated).The problem occurs with the anti forgery token. When the token is generated and when it is validated, the current identity is not the same : in one case this is the generic identity of mvc framework, in another case this is my custom identity. The 2 identities return the same name, but in some cases do not return the same value for IsAuthenticate.The name of the user is included in the anti forgery token; but if an identity is not authenticated the token does not use the name of the identity but an empty string. So the token is invalid as the name that it contain is not the name of the current identity.

So problem occurs for actions marked with ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute, when the identity has a name but is not authenticated. This is because the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute is executed before my custom PrincipalFilter.

So my question is how to ensure that my custom IAuthorizationFilter will be excuted before the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute ?
I tried to use FilterScope parameter when I register my filter, but without success.